# how do I make a function in javascript that returns an HTML element

Tags: javascript

I was writing a javascript code trying to get an HTML element

```
function getOutput(){
    return document.getElementById("output-value").innerText;
}
```

but when I make a `alert( getOutput())` the browser just sends me the lines of code above how do I fix this ?

I tried to fix it by this:

```
function getOutput(){
    return document.getElementById("output-value").innerHTML;
}
```

and also this

```
function getOutput(){
    return document.getElementById("output-value");
}
```

but none seemed to work
What should I do ?

Comment: "_but when I make a alert( getOutput()) the browser just sends me the lines of code above_" I can't reproduce that. When I use that it displays the inner text just fine. Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget the parentheses? There's a difference between `alert(getOutput())` and `alert(getOutput)`.

Comment: check your console for errors

Comment: hey doc, did my answer help ? if so, you can upvote and accept the answer. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but when I make a alert( getOutput()) the browser just sends me the lines of code above how do I fix this ?

The only way that would happen is if you put your statement inside of a quotation mark. See: `getOutputString()` function in the snippet

If you are looking to the child elements, `.innerHTML` is your thing.
And if you are trying to get the element with the id itself, then `.outerHTML` is what you are looking for.

Check the snippet:

```js
function getOutput(){
    return document.getElementById("output-value").innerHTML;
}

function getOutputString(){
    return 'document.getElementById("output-value").innerHTML;'
}

function getOutputEl(){
    return document.getElementById("output-value").outerHTML;
}


alert(getOutput());
alert(getOutputString());
alert(getOutputEl());
```

```html
<div id='output-value'>
<p>Test texts</p>
</div>
```